# How to force/guide scrolling to the nearest element only?

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, parallax, scrolltop

An example of this would be the website for [Stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/). The only problem is, I am already using a parallax library (ScrollMagic) and don't want to redo my website with Stellar. How would I do this?  (jQuery is acceptable.)

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the sections are full-page.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What do you want?

Comment: @Mohammad I want to be able to scroll like on the Stellar.js website, where if you scroll, it automatically scrolls to the nearest div with whatever class. I just don't want to have to use a whole different parallax library just for that functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by "**the nearest x**" ?

Comment: @robbie0630 You srcroll is horizontal or vertical?

Comment: @cocoseis Sorry for the unclear wording. By x I meant the nearest div with whatever class.

Comment: @Mohammad Vertical

Comment: @robbie0630 Please mark one of answer to finishing this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

This lets the user scroll and when he stops it bounces into the next position.

```js
scrollTo($(".start"));


$(document).on('mousewheel ', function(e) {

  //e.preventDefault(); /** optional, you might want to try it **/

  
  
  /** elements to bounce to: **/
  var $elements = $("div[data-scrollBolock]"); 
  
  /** get the next/previous element based on the scrolling direction: **/
  var $elementToScrollTo = $elements.eq(0);
  var scrollDirection = "down";
  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
    scrollDirection = "up";
    $elements = $($elements.get().reverse());
  }

  $elements.each(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      elementOffset = $(this).offset().top,
      distance = (elementOffset - scrollTop);
    if (scrollDirection === "down") {
      if (distance > 0) {
        $elementToScrollTo = $(this);
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      if (distance < 0) {
        $elementToScrollTo = $(this);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  
  /** scrollTo $elementToScrollTo but only if the user stopped scrolling **/
  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
  $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() { //user stopped scrolling
    scrollTo($elementToScrollTo);
  }, 80));

});


function scrollTo($el) {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($el).offset().top
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div data-scrollBolock>1</div>

<div class="start" data-scrollBolock>2</div>

<div data-scrollBolock>3</div>

<div data-scrollBolock>4</div>

<div data-scrollBolock>5</div>

<div data-scrollBolock>6</div>
```

Comment: It scrolls to the start, but I am able to scroll freely.

Comment: Did you toggle the `e.preventDefault();` comment

Comment: Ahh, no. I'll try that once I get home.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add `scroll` event handler. Use `setTimeout()` in scroll event to run your code when page scrolling finished.

```
var timer;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    clearInterval(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        scrollToElement(this);
    }, 800);
});
```

When page scrolling finished after 0.8 second, the function called. In function, you need to get height of window and scroll position. Then select all `section` in page and using `each()` to getting data of them. In `each()` you need to getting height and position of element. In last step, if result of condition is right, page scrolled to target element.

```
function scrollToElement(_this){
    var winHeight = $(_this).height();
    var scrollTop = $(_this).scrollTop();
    var winHeightHalf = winHeight / 2;    
    var winCenterScroll = scrollTop + winHeightHalf;

    $("section").each(function(){
        var elemHeight = $(this).height();
        var elementTop = $(this).position().top; 
        var elemBottomPos = elementTop + elemHeight; 

        if ((winCenterScroll > elementTop && elementTop > scrollTop) || 
            (scrollTop + winHeight > elemBottomPos && elemBottomPos > winCenterScroll))
            $("body, html").animate({scrollTop: elementTop}, "500");
    });
}
```

Because you cant see suitable result if here, see it in **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xc98yswb/)**

*Note that: height of section must be equal or less than page height and great than half of page height.*

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention that the sections take up the entire page. Works great though.

Comment: @robbie0630 There is no problem, `height` of `section` can be equal of page height.